# Bug in rejecting suggested edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

### Steps to reproduce:

---

#### Step One:

Find a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=day)

---

#### Step Two:

Click <kbd>Reject</kbd>:

[image: reject me]

---

#### Step Three:

Click on the **custom** radio:

[image: custom]

---

#### Step Four:

Click on some other radio:

[image: click other]

---

#### Conclusion:

**CANNOT** click on the reject Button. It is greyed out and unclickable (unless I put some text in the custom radio's textbox):

[image: unclickable...]

Comment: No repro, although I *was* able to click back on `custom` and [reject the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/228323) without putting in any explanatory text. It used the "Invalid Edit" reason instead. Latest version of Chrome.

Comment: I've noticed this too, but for me it's only when I choose "invalid edit". Choosing any other option after "custom" works. Clicking custom again and then "invalid edit" enables the button again. Latest Chrome on both Mac & Windows.

Comment: Pretty much every dialog with a **Custom** option has the same bug.

Comment: I can't repro exactly, but there's definitely some oddities with how the Custom reason/box work, especially with respect to the Reject button.

Comment: I can repro this 100% of the time, only happens if you click the mouse **REALLY** fast

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed in latest, a timer was firing off and disabling it within 100ms

Comment: to be deployed later