# Flag button gets perma-disabled

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

*I'm aware of the [existing question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99882/flag-a-question-dialog-bug) on this topic, but that was tagged as 'status-completed' last year so I'm assuming it had the same symptoms but a different cause.*

When flagging an answer, the pop-up with a selection of radio buttons appears for you to choose a reason.

If you select the '**other**' option (under Moderator Attention), the '*Flag Answer*' button is disabled until you enter enough accompanying text (at least 10 chars).

However, if you change your mind before typing anything and select the '**it is spam**' option instead, the button is never re-enabled and you have to close the pop-up and start again.

[image: screenshot]

I've reproduced it on IE9 and FireFox 12 so far.

**EDIT:** also reproduced in Chrome 19.0.1084.46 m

In case it's relevant, I'm accessing it via [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) on the ***Late Answers*** tab and clicking *review answer* before clicking *flag*

Comment: I'm not seeing this in Chrome 19.0.1084.46 m

Comment: @ChrisF Reproduced, same browser. The trick is to also click the "other" radio before you select "it is spam".

Comment: @YannisRizos - that's what I was doing.

Comment: @ChrisF I tested with the same Chrome version and reproduced it just now. I think it must be specific to how you trigger the pop-up: I'm doing it via [Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/) on the Late Answers tab and clicking *review answer* before clicking *flag*

Comment: @Widor - ah. I flagged from the main page.

Comment: Repro from the review page, no repro from ordinary page. SeaMonkey 2.9.

Comment: It seems to be working fine for answers when flagging from the main page, but not when flagging questions.

Comment: @DanielFischer Try reproducing with a question.

Comment: @YannisRizos Flag button enabled for questions, both from ordinary pages and /review/first_questions (I didn't actually click it, I'm just going by the looks).

Comment: Same here, also marked completed but doesn't work: [“Flag post” link is deactivated when changing flag reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102816/flag-post-link-is-deactivated-when-changing-flag-reasons)

Comment: No repro from *Late Answers*, with Chrome 19.0.1084.46 on Win 7.

Comment: Can repro on Opera 11.64 on Win 7 32-bit from review and from ordinary page, questions and answers.

Comment: @Widor this was also a bug back in March which was marked as completed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127117/155556

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA - So, there's either multiple causes, the fix has since been rolled back in a later release, or maybe **status-completed** was just a lie to shut us all up!

Comment: @Widor hehe that _may_ be.... we may never know...

Comment: Repro on IE8, for both "spam" and "not welcome", but clicking any other option will restore functionality (no need to close/reopen flag window)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logic here has been cleaned up to handle the timing issue that [Shog9 mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133430/140548).

Should be good to go with our next deploy (rev > 2012.7.24.3467).

Answer (score 12):

Reproduced on several answers here on MSO, using Chrome 19:

1. Click flag on the answer. Note the button is disabled.
2. Click directly on the "other" label. Note the button is disabled.
3. Click directly on the "spam" label. Note the button is *still* disabled.
4. Click on "it is not welcome..." - it's enabled.
5. Click back on "spam" - it's enabled.

Firefox 12 behaves properly (button is enabled as soon as "spam" is clicked), *unless* you start typing something in the "other" box. At that point, it behaves like Chrome.

---

**Update**: dug into the code here a bit - turns out it's pretty much luck as to whether or not you can reproduce this. There's a little timer that gets kicked off when the "other" textarea loses focus, that's supposed to do a final length-check after 100ms. Sometimes, that fires before the code that enables the button (and everything works fine), sometimes it fires afterwards (and the button stays disabled). This can affect both the "spam" and "not welcome" radio buttons.

Comment: Thanks for digging out the the added detail.