# Flag radio button and button disabling (for answers)

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flag button gets perma-disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133393/flag-button-gets-perma-disabled)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click `flag` on any answer
2. Check `other` option
3. Then check `it is spam` option

Expected: the button should be enabled

Actual: it is disabled

[image]

Comment: For me, it is reproducible by clicking on the text box for `other` option. Clicking on the radio button only doesn't trigger the bug.

Comment: @nhahtdh: in the latest chrome focus is sent automatically by clicking radio (at least on both my machines)

Comment: I'm testing on Safari 5.1.6.

Comment: I'm getting this bug on questions, too.

Comment: This bug has been duped in so many ways possible that I'm having a hard time finding a duplicate :(

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn: I'm wondered it's not fixed yet then ;-) Doesn't seem too difficult to deal with :-)

Comment: **Workaround:** click more slowly! (Uh, and according to myself a few months back, "be less unlucky")