# Flag Question Button is enabled when flagging for moderator attention without comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, meta

I just noticed that i can flag a question for moderator attention without providing a comment (Button Flag Question is enabled).

When i click the button i get the red error box "An error occured during flagging" and the server returns a 500 - Internal Server Error.

Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Open a question
2. Flag question to open flagging dialog (Button Flag Question is disabled)
3. Select a flag option (as example "it is spam")
4. Select "it needs moderator attention"

These steps result in that the Flag Question button is enabled, without providing any comment for the moderator.

I can only reproduce this on Meta. Stackoverflow seems to work as expected.

[image: Flagging enabled without comment]

Output Developer Tools (Chrome)

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/flags/posts/184480/add/undefined
GET http://meta.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/flags/posts/184480/add/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.min.js:4
send jquery.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4
B full.js?v=29ea9a93c321:176
(anonymous function) full.js?v=29ea9a93c321:173
f.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
h.handle.i
```

Comment: Just reproduced on this question.

Comment: It's only on Meta as they didn't roll out the change in the flagging system.

Comment: Misleading title - you didn't actually raise a flag. Also I cannot reproduce this in Firefox.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn i´ve changed the title. may be its better now. I can reproduce it with FireFox

Comment: @Bolt step #3 is crucial, sure you followed it? :)

Comment: Reproduced by me (Firefox 21, Windows 7). The button is correctly disabled if you click the `other` option under `flag for moderator attention`; without clicking `other`, the button stays enabled.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133393/flag-button-gets-perma-disabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a duff check in JavaScript for this particular bit.

Don't you love 1 character fixes?

Anyhow. Fixed.

Comment: While you're at it, another dish for you this time in the close dialog: close --> off topic --> choose any --> click "Closing" to get back --> button still enabled, no close reason selected. Submitting result in error. :-/

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd the same is true for selecting `duplicate` and then go back

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Thanks. Fix is in the oven. Should be served in the next 5 minutes or so.

Comment: @Oded you would be good candidate for MasterChef! :D